# Rabbitmqadmin can't open with no error

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqadmin

I installed correctly RabbitMQ. It is working. I also enabled RabbitMQ management plugin with:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

after that any rabbitmqadmin commands do not seem to work and no error is displayed :

```
root@jessie:/usr# rabbitmqadmin --help
root@jessie:/usr#
```

what can I do ?

Comment: Did you make sure that the service is started ? 
(To start the service:
service rabbitmq-server start). What happens when you run :
service rabbitmq-server status

Comment: When I run RabbitMQ, It's say nothing.
`root@jessie:~# sudo service rabbitmq-server start
root@jessie:~# `           But  when i run `service --status-all` command, it shows that `[ + ]  rabbitmq-server`. If I stop RabbitMQ,  it say  `[ -]  rabbitmq-server`. And I am using RabbitMQ in my project.  All other RabbitMQ functions work correctly, only RabbitMQAdmin didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to make sure you have installed python, check your python version using below commands,

```
python -V or python3 -V
```

if it's python 3 you have to change the header of the rabbitmqadmin script as below,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

otherwise it won't work.

Now make sure you give the permission by chmod 777 and run scripts as below,

To list down ques,

```
./rabbitmqadmin -f tsv -q list queues
```